# Setting up basic proxy from https to http via Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, proxy, https, mod-proxy

I need to proxy some remote api `https://example.com/api/`

to be accessible locally as `http://localhost/api/`

I tried putting this line in `httpd.conf`:

```
 ProxyPass     /api/     https://example.com/api/
```

I have checked these modules are enabled:

```
 ssl_module, proxy_module, proxy_http_module
```

When I'm trying to reach `http://localhost/api/`, I'm getting 500 Internal Server Error, And what I see in `error_log` is:

```
[Wed Jan 14 16:42:04.788401 2015] [proxy:warn] [pid 21916] [client ::1:59260] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /api/v1/ads. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

My question is relative to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997001/setting-up-a-basic-web-proxy-in-apache. Actually, when I try to proxy http resources, everything works for me, so the problem is somewhere around SSL.

The reason I want this to work is the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` problem I'm experiencing when working with remote api locally.

---

UPDATE

Here's the entire conf file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/mkrxna4h2o9yu8k/httpd.conf?dl=0

Comment: This question can have an answer on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130303/apache-config-how-to-proxypass-http-requests-to-https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be all you need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ https://example.com/api/$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

Apache will basically proxy your requests by creating new http requests via the mod_rewrite module, which is enabled by default

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! I've uploaded the entire conf file and attached it to the question.  Btw, after applying your answer, I get the following in error_log: [ssl:error] [pid 22221] [remote 54.149.6.238:443] AH01961: SSL Proxy requested for macs-MacBook-Pro.local:80 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]
[Wed Jan 14 17:49:37.661756 2015] [proxy:error] [pid 22221] AH00961: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for 54.149.6.238:443 (api-staging.ad-rapid.com)

Comment: Plus check if `rewrite_module` module is on, I suggest

Comment: Make sure you have this too: "SSLProxyEngine on".

Comment: And that worked!